# How to generate a .ipa file from my app using Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Visual Studio community 2022 and Xamarin to create a mobile app which is compatible with both iOS and Android. I would like to be able to download the app on my iPhone so I can test it properly and eventually be able to share the app with other people. I have been able to archive the Android version of my app (generate the .apk file) with Visual Studio since, from what I gather, I have an Android simulator in my computer. However, I am unable to archive the iOS version of my app and generate a .ipa file because I don't have such a simulator on my computer. I can't use my iPhone to play it since I don't have an Apple Developer account (and getting one would cost me $119 CAD which I'm not very eager to pay) so the remaining solution would be to pair to a Mac computer.
I own a Mac computer, but I don't use it anymore since it was getting pretty old (Macbook pro purchased in 2013). When I try and pair to my mac, I get the same error message every time and I don't know what to do about it:
"An error occurred while trying to establish an SSH connection with SSH keys to"
followed by my mac's IP address. However, even if I managed to pair my mac to visual studio on my Windows computer, I have a feeling I would still be unable to sign my code without the Apple Developer account.
I've tried many things:

- I've downloaded Visual Studio for mac on my mac and run the code, but since my mac is old the version of xamarin I used in my code is incompatible with the versions of XCode and Visual Studio I can download.
- When that failed, I've tried doing what's indicated on this website but I didn't succeed since archiving the app always failed, because the XCode version I can download isn't recent enough (I can only download version 12.4 and I need at least 13.3)
  -I've looked a lot into signing the app without paying $119 to Apple for a developer account but have found nothing else.
  If anyone has any suggestions about how to potentially get the .ipa file it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: you need a Mac that can run the current version of XCode.  You may be able to produce a build with a CI service like ADO or AppCenter.ms

Comment: I forgot to add, I uploaded my app to AppCenter, but when I try and build the app I get the following error: ##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_12_12/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.

Comment: and regardless, you will need an Apple dev account in order to deploy to a device

Comment: You can use a free apple developer account with some restrictions; you can only register a single, physical, iOS device. Builds are only valid for 7 days and some app features are not available

Comment: But if the build is only valid for seven days, I won't be able to distribute it to other devices?

Comment: Save the IPA file and you can distribute the IPA through AppCenter.ms .